# Infinite slideshow function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a basic slideshow using jQuery for use in future projects. I have sorted the function so that the divs (will be images but it doesn't  really matter right now) all fade in and out at the right times. However I don't know how to repeat it.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slide").hide();
    var $slideshow = function() {
        $("#one").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#two").delay(5000).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#three").delay(10000).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#four").delay(15000).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
        $("#five").delay(20000).fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
    };
    $slideshow();
});
```

I have tried adding $slideshow(); at the end of the function, but it turned out really buggy; it took about 10 seconds to load and the timing/order wasn't right.

Here is a jsfiddle to make it easier to see: http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/8PTCf/

Also, is this the most efficient way of doing this? It just seems like a lot of code for a basic function.

Comment: TBH you are trying to re-invent the wheel somewhat here. You're certainly not the first person to ever want and invent this functionality snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow simonbattersby.com/blog/simple-jquery-image-crossfade wowslider.com/rq/jquery-image-crossfade perhaps better off implementing one of the many other solutions

Comment: @Rob - fair point, I think I've got too used to implementing other's ideas and not learning so much though (jQuery is still very new to me). This is why I'm trying to figure things out for myself, learning things along the way, whilst writing useful bits of code for later use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a super simple one I use using a setInterval. You can also add slides and just change `if (n > 5)` 5 being the max number of slides. It just counts up and when it gets to the max, resets back to 1. Heres a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x28b9/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".slide").hide();
var $slideshow = function() {
    var n = 1;
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".slide").fadeOut();
        $("#slide-"+n).fadeIn();
        n = n+1;
        if(n > 5){
            n = 1;
        }
    },3500);
};
    $slideshow();
});
```

Comment: This is a simple solution but less dynamic as you have to *potentially* set the CSS for everyone but since these are probably images with differing `src` attributes that's not too much of a bind.  However the id's do have to be set manually for each image.

Comment: @Rob Schmuecker Agreed, this is a simple solution. Although, in terms of the CSS, you could name the id's anything you want and use 'data-set' instead. Then use $('.slide').attr('data-set'); to call each slide. As for dynamically loading in slides, You could also set use an $.each or for loop to set each slide and have it include the n in the data-set. This is just something to build off.

Comment: My point being more that you `have` to have a unique attribute, call id `id` or a `data-attribute`.  Agree this is something to build off +1

Answer (score 3):

use `eq` selector in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide").hide();
    var slideshow = function (val) {
        $(".slide:eq(" + val + ")").fadeIn("slow").delay(100).fadeOut("slow", function () {
         if ($(".slide").length - 1 > val) {
            slideshow(val + 1);
           }else{
             slideshow(0);
          }
        });


    }


    slideshow(0);
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8PTCf/3/)

Comment: That still stops after 1 loop of it though.. Also, with each transition, there is a point where nothing is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an infinite version which can take as many slides as you put in a designated `slideContainer`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".slide").hide();
    var duration = 500;
    var slideIterator = 0;
    var $slideshow = function (slideContainer) {
        if (slideIterator < $(slideContainer).children().length) {
            var slide = $($(slideContainer).children()[slideIterator]);
            slide.fadeIn("slow", function () {
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(that).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                        slideIterator++;
                        $slideshow(slideContainer);
                    });
                }, duration);
            });

        } else {
            slideIterator = 0;
            $slideshow(slideContainer);
        }
    }
    $slideshow('#slideshow');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/8PTCf/5/

Comment: Very almost perfect, the one thing I don't like is how with each change, there is a point where nothing is showing. I think it might look better how mine worked in that as one faded out, another faded in, but other than that it's a great solution.

Comment: +1 @Hamish true! You're solutions is certainly neater.